# When a pro-$p$ group of finite rank can be embedded into the first congruence subgroup of ${\rm GL}_{N}(\mathbb{Z}_{p})$

Tags: gr.group-theory, profinite-groups, p-adic-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}$Let $p$ be a odd prime. We say that a pro-$p$ group has *finite rank* if it is isomorphic to a closed subgroup of $\GL_d(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ for some integer $d$. A pro-$p$ group $G$ is called *FAb* if $U^{\text{ab}}$ is finite for all open subgroups $U$ of $G$ where $U^{\text{ab}}$ denotes the abelianization of $U$. For example, any open pro-$p$ subgroup of $\SL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ is FAb. We will denote the first congruence subgroup of $\GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ by $\GL_{n}^{1}(\mathbb{Z}_p)$, i.e.
$$\GL_{n}^{1}(\mathbb{Z}_p):=\ker(\GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)\to \GL_n(\mathbb{F}_p)).$$

**Question:**
Suppose that $G$ is a torsion-free pro-$p$ group of finite rank.

1. Is there a positive integer $N$ such that $G$ admits an injective homomorphism $G\to \GL_{N}^{1}(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ ?
2. Assume further that $G$ is FAb. Is there an affirmative answer to Question 1? Note that we may assume that $G$ is non-solvable in this case. (Otherwise, it must be trivial.)
3. If the answer to the Question 1 is no, then is it possible to give some sufficient condtions?

Comment: Oops, sorry. I only arranged that the determinant of the reduction mod $p$ is 1. I erased my comment.

Comment: I think that the most important part of this question is that you have a chance to incorporate base change somehow and ask whether a group is absolutely FAb. \\ Seriously, this is an interesting question.  Why do you exclude $p = 2$?  Do you know counterexamples, or is it just the usual feeling that *something* will go wrong for $p = 2$?

Comment: @LSpice Thanks for your comment. I do not know a counterexample to the case of $p=2$, and I just want to keep it simple in some sense.

Comment: @LSpice +1 for the sitcom reference

Answer (score 3):

The answer to 1 is No. By Corollary 4.5 and Example 4.2 in [Analytic pro-p groups of small dimensions](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/JGT.2009.006/html), we see that

> Every $p$-adic analytic pro-$p$ group of dimension $p$ which embeds into a saturable pro-$p$ group is itself saturable. On the other hand, there exists a torsion-free $p$-adic analytic pro-$p$ group of dimension $p$ which is not saturable.

In other words, any torsion-free $p$-adic analytic pro-$p$ group of dimension $p$ which is not saturable cannot be embeded into a saturable pro-$p$ group, and there really exist torsion-free $p$-adic analytic pro-$p$ group $G$ of dimension $p$ which is not saturable. Since ${\rm GL}_{n}^{1}(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ is saturable, this gives a counterexample to Question 1. However, the group $G$ in the above example is not FAb. So I still don't know the answer to Question 2.

Comment: For those without access to the article, can you describe the non-saturable group?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg https://arxiv.org/abs/0806.2968